# Save VTK point cloud data from rendering window members

Tags: c++, qt, io, vtk

I am working on a Qt program built around a MainWindow containing a `qvtkWidget`.

I am displaying various VTK objects within the `qvtkWidget`, with the objective to alter them after they have been loaded and rendered. The altered data set should then be written to a file for later reuse.

For instance, I am displaying an instance of `vtkPointSource` after generating the former and passing it to an instance of `vtkPolyDataMapper`, itself passed to an instance of `vtkActor`, itself passed to an instance of `vtkRenderer`. The renderer is then added to the `qvtkWidget` and properly displayed.

Let's imagine that one now desires to save the point cloud to a .vtp file.

`vtkXMLPolyDataWriter` would do the trick once provided with a vtkPolyData object representing the point cloud being displayed.

I was thinking I could retrieve the underlying point cloud data by doing the following inside MainWindow::save() :

```
vtkRenderWindow * renderWindow = this->qvtkWidget->GetRenderWindow();
vtkRendererCollection * renderers = renderWindow-> GetRenderers();
vtkRenderer * renderer = renderers->GetFirstRenderer();
vtkActorCollection * actors = renderer->GetActors();
vtkActor * actor = actors->GetLastActor();
vtkPolyDataMapper * mapper = actor->GetMapper();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> * polydata = mapper->GetInput()
```

A casting error occurs at `vtkPolyDataMapper * mapper = actor->GetMapper();` which makes complete sense given the inheritance relationship between `vtkPolyDataMapper` and `vtkMapper`.

I guess I could instead rewrite the last two lines to

```
vtkMapper * mapper = actor->GetMapper();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkDataSet> * polydata = mapper->GetInput()
```

to avoid the cast error, but I am not certain at all that the above code snippet is respecting VTK I/O standards.

Is this a correct approach for saving point cloud data to file after it has been altered (i.e, going from the rendering window to the underlying data set in the presented way)?